Prisma relationship create return error even when almost similar function doesn't
I created 2 Models in prisma using a third one in relationship. nothing new there, i did it dozens of time but I getting an error in VSCode for one of the create function.
model Project {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  description String?
  fileId      Int?      
  file        File?     @relation(fields: [fileId], references: [id])
  createdAt   DateTime? @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime? 
}


model App {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  description String?
  fileId      Int?      
  file        File?     @relation(fields: [fileId], references: [id])
  url         String?
  createdAt   DateTime? @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime?
}


model File {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  type        String
  path        String  @unique
  createdAt   DateTime? @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime? 

  projects   Project[]
  apps       App[]
}

Project and App both using File. I then have 2 function doing the saving.

  const app = await prisma.app.create({
    data: {
      name,
      description,
      url,
      file: {
        create: {
          name: name,
          path: newName,
          type: mimeType,
        },
      }
    },
  });


  const project = await prisma.project.create({
    data: {
      name,
      file: {
        create: {
          name: name,
          path: newName,
          type: mimeType,
        },
      }
    },
  });

the app function has no issue, however VSCode mark the second one as error, returning this:

Type '{ name: any; Id: number; file: { create: { name: any; path: string; type: any; }; }; createdAt: Date; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<ProjectCreateInput, ProjectUncheckedCreateInput> & ProjectUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & ProjectCreateInput)'.
Types of property 'file' are incompatible.
Type '{ create: { name: any; path: string; type: any; }; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(9958, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: ProjectSelect | null | undefined; include?: ProjectInclude | null | undefined; data: (Without<...> & ProjectUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & ProjectCreateInput); }'
(property) data: (Prisma.Without<Prisma.ProjectCreateInput, Prisma.ProjectUncheckedCreateInput> & Prisma.ProjectUncheckedCreateInput) | (Prisma.Without<...> & Prisma.ProjectCreateInput)
The data needed to create a Project.

I don't understand where the error is. I also have the same setup using File model this way in other 2 Models, that all work exactly like App model, without issue.
All saving data is correct, I really don't know why one is fine and the other is not.
